# Python PySide2: Launch QDialog with buttons and wait for response

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to get an application to start with a username/password dialog.  After the user enters their username/password, the main dialog should appear.  My problem is that the dialog is not blocking, so the login prompt appears, but so does the main window.  How can I get the application to wait for input from the dialog before continuing?

Also, how can I get the username and password that are entered in the prompt?  Would I have to create a slot to store the values somewhere?

And I may be going about the creation/display of the login window completely wrong, so feel free to steer me in a different direction.

main.py

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow
from loginPrompt import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)   

login = QDialog()
login.ui = Ui_Login()
login.ui.setupUi(login)

login.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

login.show()           # This shows the login prompt

w = MyForm(arguments)  # This creates and shows the main part of my application
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

loginPrompt.py

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login):
        Login.setObjectName("Login")
        Login.resize(471, 113)
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(Login)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.le_username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Login)
        self.le_username.setObjectName("le_username")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.le_username)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Login)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.le_password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Login)
        self.le_password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.le_password.setObjectName("le_password")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.le_password)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Login)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(Login)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Login.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Login.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)

    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Login", "Username"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Login", "Password"))
```

The code continues to execute after `login.show()`.  I need it to wait there until one of the buttons is pressed (OK or Cancel).

Comment: Change `login.show()` to `login.exec_()`

Comment: wow, that was easy :)